# Modifying block matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to take a matrix and modify blocks of it. For example, with a 4x4 matrix the {1,2},{1,2} block is to the top left quadrant ([0,1;4,5] below). The {4,1},{4,1} block is the top left quadrant if we rearrange the matrix so the 4th row/column is in position 1 and the 1st in position 2.

Let's made such a 4x4 matrix:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
print(a)

## [[ 0  1  2  3]
##  [ 4  5  6  7]
##  [ 8  9 10 11]
##  [12 13 14 15]]
```

Now one way of selecting the block, where I specify which rows/columns I want beforehand, is as follows:

```
C=[3,0]
a[[[C[0],C[0]],[C[1],C[1]]],[[C[0],C[1]],[C[0],C[1]]]]

## array([[15, 12],
##        [ 3,  0]])
```

Here's another way:

```
a[C,:][:,C]

## array([[15, 12],
##        [ 3,  0]])
```

Yet, if I have a 2x2 array, call it b, setting

```
a[C,:][:,C]=b
```

doesn't work but

```
a[[[C[0],C[0]],[C[1],C[1]]],[[C[0],C[1]],[C[0],C[1]]]]=b
```

does.

Why is this? And is this second way the most efficient possible? Thanks!

Comment: If C was a numpy array then `a[C[:,None], C]` would work as well.

Comment: Ashwini: when I try that I get 'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple'?

Comment: You want `a[np.ix_(C, C)] = b`

Comment: @user65257 I did say: "If C was a numpy array", so it won't work with a list.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant section from the numpy docs is
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing
Advanced array indexing.

Adapting that example to your case:

```
In [213]: rows=np.array([[C[0],C[0]],[C[1],C[1]]])
In [214]: cols=np.array([[C[0],C[1]],[C[0],C[1]]])

In [215]: rows
array([[3, 3],
       [0, 0]])

In [216]: cols
array([[3, 0],
       [3, 0]])

In [217]: a[rows,cols]
array([[15, 12],
       [ 3,  0]])
```

due to broadcasting, you don't need to repeat duplicate indices, thus:

```
a[[[3],[0]],[3,0]]
```

does just fine.  `np.ix_` is a convenience function to produce just such a pair:

```
np.ix_(C,C) 
(array([[3],
        [0]]), 
 array([[3, 0]]))
```

thus a short answer is:

```
a[np.ix_(C,C)]
```

A related function is `meshgrid`, which constructs full indexing arrays:

```
a[np.meshgrid(C,C,indexing='ij')]
```

`np.meshgrid(C,C,indexing='ij')` is the same as your `[rows, cols]`.  See the functions doc for the significance of the `'ij'` parameter.

`np.meshgrid(C,C,indexing='ij',sparse=True)` produces the same pair of arrays as `np.ix_`.

I don't think there's a serious difference in computational speed.  Obviously some require less typing on your part.

`a[:,C][C,:]` works for viewing values, but not for modifying them.  The details have to do with which actions make `views` and which make copies.  The simple answer is, use only one layer of indexing if you want to modify values.

The indexing documentation:

> Thus, x[ind1,...,ind2,:] acts like x[ind1][...,ind2,:] under basic slicing.

Thus `a[1][3] += 7` works.  But the doc also warns

> Warning
>   The above is not true for advanced indexing.