# How can I update a 2 dimension array with h5py?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

I want to store a 2 dimensional array with hdf5 and have troubles to update it.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

# create a new storage
fh = h5py.File('dummy.h5', 'w')
fh.create_dataset('random', data=np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]]))
fh.close()

# try to change the first array cell to value 6
fh = h5py.File('dummy.h5', 'a')
fh['random'][0][0] = 6
fh.close()

# read the array and print out the value at the first position
fh = h5py.File('dummy.h5', 'r')
print fh['random'][0][0] # print out '0' not '6'
fh.close()
```

This code works on a normal 1 dim array. How does it works with a 2 dim array?

Comment: Generally it is better to access 2d (or larger) `numpy` arrays with the `[0,0]` syntax, rather than `[0][0]`, especially when setting values.  Read the numpy docs (or SO) regarding views v. copies for more details).

Comment: More on `[][]` v `[,]` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28575155/901925.  Also `h5py` does not behave exactly like `numpy`.  It tries to follow the same API, but implementation details differ.  So marginal syntax that works in `numpy` might not work with `h5py` arrays.

Comment: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernhard,

This is a great question. I have a quick workaround, but too shallow an understanding of h5py (and hdf5) to know why this works but your approach doesn't.

### Quick answer / workaround

Indexing by tuple, i.e. `arr[x,y]` instead of `arr[x][y]` *does* work (lines 10 and 11 below):

```
In [2]: fh = h5py.File('dummy.h5','a')
In [6]: fh['random'].value
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
In [8]: fh['random'][0][0] = 6
In [9]: fh['random'].value
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
In [10]: fh['random'][0,0] = 6
In [11]: fh['random'].value
Out[11]: 
array([[6, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```